# Snowflake how to escape all special characters in a string of an array of objects before we parse it as JSON?

Tags: json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, file-format

We are loading data into Snowflake using a JavaScript procedure.

The script will loop over an array of objects to load some data. These objects contain string that may have special characters.

i.e.:

> "Description": "This file contain "sensitive" information."

The double quotes on sensitive word will become:

> "Description": "This file contain \"sensitive\" information."

Which broke the loading script.

The same issue happened when we used HTML tags within description key:

> "Description": "Please use <b>specific fonts</b> to update the file".

This [is another example](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-parse-special-characters-in-PARSE-JSON-function) on the Snowflake community site.

Also [this post](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Use-of-escape-option-in-file-format) recommended setting `FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY` equal to the special characters, but I am handling large data set which might have all the special characters.

How can we escape special characters automatically without updating the script and use JavaScript to loop over the whole array to anticipate and replace each special character with something else?

**EDIT**

I tried using [JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/json_extract_path_text.html?_ga=2.50202342.1386997118.1640001173-1841635376.1603180645):

```
select JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT(parse_json('{
    "description": "Please use \"Custom\" fonts"
  }'), 'description');
```

and got the following error:

> Error parsing JSON: missing comma, line 2, pos 33.

Comment: Can you share your logic inside the SP? Have you tried using Bind Variables?

Comment: @EricLin it is a simple javascript recursive function looping over a file to build the array of objects, and another merge statement to merge this array into a table.

Answer (score 1):

I think the escape characters generated by the JS procedure are escaped when passing to SQL functions.

```
'{"description": "Please use \"Custom\" fonts"}'
```

becomes

```
'{"description": "Please use "Custom" fonts"}'
```

Therefore parsing them as JSON/fetching a field from JSON fails. To avoid error, the JavaScript procedure should generate a double backslash instead of a backslash:

```
'{"description": "Please use \\"Custom\\" fonts"}'
```

I do not think there is a way to prevent this error without modifying the JavaScript procedure.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this today, Gokhan is right you need the double backslashes to properly escape the quote.

Here are a couple links that explain it a little more:

- https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Escaping-new-line-character-in-JSON-to-avoid-data-loading-errors
- https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Unable-to-Insert-Data-Containing-Back-Slash-from-Stored-Procedure

For my case I found that I could address this challenge by disabling the escaping and then manually replacing the using replace function.

For your example the replace is not necessary.

```
select parse_json($${"description": "Please use \"Custom\" fonts"}$$);
select parse_json($${"description": "Please use \"Custom\" fonts"}$$):description;
```